# Typescript with context Api integration issue

Tags: typescript

I have those 3 codes, I want to switch theme from a component using contextAPI, and am getting the flowing error :

(Type '(state: string) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.ts(2322)
ModalState.tsx(13, 3): The expected type comes from property 'SwitchTheme' which is declared here on type 'themeContext')
on SwitchTheme, in the AppStateContext.Provider value any clue what i am missing ?

```js
// Context + State Logic 
import { type } from 'os';
import React, { useState, createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import ModalReducer from './modalReducer';

// Declare interfaces
interface themeContext {
  dark: false;
  SwitchTheme?: () => void;
}

const defaultState: themeContext = {
  dark: false,
};

// Create context
export const AppStateContext = createContext<themeContext>(defaultState);
// Create a single type for now
export const SET_THEME = 'SET_THEME';
// Create provider component
const AppStateProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ModalReducer, defaultState);


  // Action Fuction 
  const SwitchTheme = (state: string) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_THEME,
      state: state,
    });
  };

  return (
    <AppStateContext.Provider
      value={{
        darktheme: state.darktheme,
        SwitchTheme,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppStateContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AppStateProvider;
```

```js
// Reducer Logic 
import { SET_THEME } from './AppState';

export default (state: any, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_THEME:
      return {
        ...state,
        darktheme: action.state,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

> 

```js
// Inside Component Function 
  const switchTheme = () => {
    context.SwitchTheme(true);
  };
```